# Crystal report static parameter and multiple values

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a report that takes multiple values. 
parameter {?names} with [Allow multiple values] = "True" 
The problem is report gets an error if I try to include over 5000 names.. :

**:The%20request%20could%20not%20be%20submitted%20for%20background%20processing.%20%20%20at%20CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions%20pExportOptions,%20RequestContext%20pRequestContext)%20%20%20at%20CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext%20reqContext)%20%20%20---%20End%20of%20inner%20exception%20stack%20trace%20---%20%20%20at%20CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception%20e)%20%20%20at%20CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext%20reqContext)%20%20%20at%20CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext%20reqContext)%20%20%20at%20CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext%20reqContext)%20%20%20at%20CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export()%20%20%20at%20CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Export()%20%20%20at%20Web.WCF.MatrixReports.GenerateReport(String%20reportName,%20ObservableCollection%601%20reportParameters)%20in%20D:**

The application is silverlight.
Strange thing is if I run this app on local machine with local ASP.net development server, i can generate more than 5000, but if I try the same on the server, I get an error..

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the registry entry on the server is set to its default of 1000.

On the server:
 - Create the registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 11.5\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV 
 - Add a string value named 'MaxRowsetRecords'
 - Set to 50000
 - Restart service

You'll have to ensure that the version (the 'Suite 11.5' bit) is consistent w/ your version.